# How do I generate getters and setters dynamically in JS?

Tags: javascript, function, template-literals

I have an object with some properties and I want to loop though and generate getters for each, Any ideas ? Without using Proxy?

```js
const obj = {
  _count1: 0,
  _count2: 23,
  _count3: 1,
};

for (const key in object) {
  if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(object, key)) {
    // ?
   }
  }
}
```

Like this

```js
const x = {
  _count: 0,
  get count() {
     return this._count;
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "generate getters"? It's not clear what you want

Comment: I want every single property in the `obj` to have a getter function, the structure of the getter doesn't matter, like it could be just `return ...`. Like I showed

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to achieve. Are you referring to ES5-style [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)? What's the goal here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```js
const obj = {
  _count1: 0,
  _count2: 23,
  _count3: 1,
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj))
  Object.defineProperty(obj, key.slice(1), {
      get () { return obj[key]; },
      set (value) { obj[key] = value; }
  });

obj.count2 = 34;
console.log(obj.count2)
```

Comment: That's what I'm talking about!